# List in list method recording

Tags: python, list, variables

is any ways to access to element 'A' in the list [[A, B], [C, D]] except this way:

> > list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
> >
> > elements = list [0]
> >
> > a = elements [0]

something shorter in one string? 
thanks

Comment: Don't use `list` as an identifier since it is the name of a built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the intermediate variable:

```
a = list[0][0]
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to attempt your answer yesterday